# What does the P-value tell me in this case?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value

I've made a mosaic plot in R - I know that the colors suggest the deviance from the expected value. But how do I explain the P-value? That the deviance is not due to chance?

[image]

Comment: The documentation should explain which statistical test is used.

Comment: Are you talking about the documentation of the mosaic plot function? Because that still does not get me anywhere...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because of mixed reasons. Basically it seems to ask for interpretation of the 'p-value' (which many resources already explain, also on this website, so it is a bit **duplicate**), and it has a lot of vague introduction/context about mosaic which is not very well explained (**unclear**). also it is a bit about a software implementation of statistics rather than statistics itself (**of-topic**).

Comment: I don't know what it means to close a question, but this question seems to ask about the connection between visual display and p-value...a question I receive from my students in many different, but related, forms.

Answer (score 2):

The plot is providing a graphical representation of the chi-square test for independence. (In the 2x2 context, the same test as asking if two groups have the same proportion.) The null hypothesis is that $H_0$: $\pi_1=\pi_2$. Thus, the $P$-value you found indicates the distance between your observed percentages for the two groups is unlikely due to chance if the population percents are equal.

Comment: Some more information: https://towardsdatascience.com/mosaic-plot-and-chi-square-test-c41b1a527ce4